# want to access variable from one activity to another in automation in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I want to check whether, can we access the variable which defines at script activity across other steps within the same automation in marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly as each activity has it's own scope - after a Script Activity completes, the variables used there cease to exist.

You could work around this and store the value of your variable in some sort of temporary DE. To avoid problems, you could clear at the end (or start) of each automation run.